# getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with EditText wrapped in Text Input Layout. On API version 28 +-2 it works fine, but on version 25 it gives this error:

W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection

At the same time, the focus with EditText is lost and switches to
android.viewpager 2.widget.ViewPager2$RecyclerViewImpl{738f416 VFED..... .F...... 0,0-1028,846 #1} ( video from logs).

I can't solve this problem in any way, who can help

Comment: An InputConnection is the connection between your app and the keyboard app.  All those functions are functions on the inputConnection object that the keyboard uses to get data about the view we're sending text to.  An inactive InputConnection occurs when an InputConnection is severed-  when text is no longer being sent to that view.  This usually happens around changes of focus if the keyboard app is doing anything asynchronously, or around the keyboard being closed.

Comment: I'd be looking at your code for anything that causes you to change focus.  If you set an onFocusChangedListener and put a breakpoint in there, you may be able to see where the focus change is coming from.  I'd put it on both views-  the one losing focus and the one gaining.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.